# mysqli_insert_id on compound query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the last auto increment id on a table, but it always returns '0'.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (SELECT * FROM tmptable)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$newId = mysqli_insert_id($link); //$newID ends up being 0
```

The `id` column of the `inventory` table is set to auto increment, and `mysqli_insert_id()` works fine on other `INSERT` queries to `inventory` that aren't inserting the result of a `SELECT` statement. Is the `SELECT` statement taking precedence as the last query for some reason, which would cause `mysqli_insert_id()` to return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` incorrectly.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id It's the server feature underlying [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

First, your INSERT statement doesn't mention a list of column names. That means it's inserting information into all the columns of the target table, including the autoincrementing column. When you specify the value of the autoincrementing column in your INSERT, you disable the autoincrementing feature, so you get zero back instead of an actual `id` value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Second, if you insert more than one row, you only will get the id value of the first row inserted.

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case. I stopped trying to be so clever and got the result of the SELECT statement beforehand, saved it's fields to variables and did a normal INSERT. At that point, mysqli_insert_id worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer involves **table locking** so in heavy traffic websites it might degrade performance (assuming your auto increment column is "id").

```
mysqli_query($link, "LOCK TABLE inventory WRITE,tmptable READ");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO inventory (SELECT * FROM tmptable)");
$r = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(id) FROM inventory");
mysqli_query($link, "UNLOCK TABLES");
```